# Is there a gentle way of stopping processes using Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have to stop a browser from a PowerShell script, which I do by piping it into

```
Stop-Process -Force
```

However, this is very abrupt. When the browser is restarted, it detects that it didn't shut down cleanly, and tries to restart the previous session. Is there some way I can tell it to shut itself down gracefully? ("There are two ways we can do this ...")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this to simulate the user closing the app:

```
(Get-Process -Id 10024).CloseMainWindow()
```

Answer (score 11):

Keith Hill has already proposed to use CloseMainWindow(). But it is only an invitation to close, some user interaction still might be needed, for example an application may show some dialogs to save something and etc. If a calling script really expects a process to be exited, I use this pattern:

```
# close the window and wait for exit
$_ = Get-Process -Id 12345
[void]$_.CloseMainWindow()
if (!$_.HasExited) {
    Write-Host "Waiting for exit of Pid=$($_.Id)..."
    $_.WaitForExit()
}
```

Comment: I also had to change my Chrome startup settings from "Continue where you left off" to "Open the New Tab page". This allowed the process that is opening Chrome to start without opening the last sessions tabs along side the new tabs.

Comment: Important hint. But assigning to `$_` seems a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
Get-Process <name> | where {$_.MainWindowHandle -ne [System.IntPtr]::Zero} | foreach {$_.CloseMainWindow()}
```

This will close all processes that match the pattern and have a window attached to them. For example, Chrome process may use subprocesses that do not have a window. These subprocesses will be ignored.

Comment: FYI - this command does work as long as there actually is a process with the given name, otherwise it errors out. The error may or may not be desired depending on your use case.